# Send text data to ip/port lenghth-prefixed case

Tags: vb.net

I want to send some data (text) to specific IP/port within same network. I know my code is good enough, but i heard something about "But it is adviced to use something like length-prefixed messages" - could anyone of you tell me what is that true, and if so then what should i change within my code to what?

```
 ''' <summary>
    ''' Send data over TCP/IP network
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="data">Data string to write</param>
    ''' <param name="IP">The connected destination TcpClient</param>
    Public Sub WriteData(ByVal data As String, ByRef IP As String)
        Console.WriteLine("Sending message """ & data & """ to " & IP)
        Dim client As TcpClient = New TcpClient()
        client.Connect(New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), My.Settings.CommPort))
        Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
        Dim sendBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data)
        stream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
    End Sub
```

Comment: You'd use length-prefixed messages if you're sending this between your own application(s). For other applications you'd have to follow their design.

Comment: If you are for example creating a file transfer application or a chat/message application you'd use length-prefixing to ensure that all the data is sent and read correctly (so that you don't get partial data). But since you're making this for a label printer you'd have to follow it's design instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my opinions:

- In general, in the data communication context, message `header` is
  good to have (including `Length` of the message - which could be put
  as part of the `header`), especially when your data is of various
  types and of various length.
- This is because in the receiver site, it can choose how to handle the
  incoming data *before* all data is received completely.

  1. For instance, if you have two data types: very long text and highly-compressed images. The header (which is the first to be received in the receiver side) will tell immediately what kind of data the receiver is receiving.
  2. If it is a very long text, then it can process it (like displaying the partial content) before the stream is finished, but in highly compressed image it cannot be done.
- Think also in the case where you may receive multiple (different)
  data from the sender and from the same ports. In such case, having
  header per message sending will really help the receiver to know,
  which message belong to which data and not concat them wrongly.
- Thus, in this context, prefixed-length can also be put as part of the
  `header` - assuming your receiver may receive various data with
  variable length. By this, it also knows exactly when to consider the data
  communication "completed" to form a *complete* packet.

This is not finished though... you may normally want to check the integrity of the packet received (by having suffix/appended message like CRC) or some kind of encryption/decryption.

But the general idea is that it is good to have it for the mentioned reasons.

Comment: can i do something without having phisical access to the receiver - in my case it will be label printer - my client knows only what IP and port text data has to be sent - that's it and that's all i know unfortunetly - there is also noone right know to give me some specific konwledge - he says thats enough you to send text to this ip and port. Do you think can i do something without further knowledge from client or i have to stay with what i just have in that situation?

Comment: @JohnDoe that's not really a robust design. But since it is printing case with internal network, Assuming that your network connection cannot be suddenly broken and there will only be one sending at a time from one client (that is client IP address)... Then if I were to settle this issue, I would implement `timeout` check. So if you receive a printing request, you mark the time the request is received. And as long as there is data received from that client, you keep updating the last time received. If you do not receive anymore data for, say, 3 seconds, then you assume the data is completed.

Comment: @JohnDoe so by `timeout` check you can start processing the data as soon as the `timeout` occur. Perhaps you can do it that way...

Comment: ccould one of you would be so kind and show me how should i modyfi my code according to what has been told

Comment: @JohnDoe : Length-prefixing won't do any good if the endpoint (in this case the label printer) doesn't support it! - Which I'm 99,99% sure it don't.

Comment: @JohnDoe as Visual Vincent mentions, the data format between two endpoints must be known before we can make the data in any format. In other words, this is case specific.